# Discord.py - how to delete message if a specific user is mentioned

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make an on_message event where if an admin is mentioned it will delete that message and then tell them they can't do that. Here is my code right now

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
admin_id = "<@496186362886619138>"
    if admin_id in message.content:
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send("You can't do that")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took another look at the documentation and found `mentioned_in()` and `Client.fetch_user()`.
My final code looks like this:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
        # DELETE ADMIN MENTION
    user = await bot.fetch_user(496186362886619138)
    if user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send("You can't do that")
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Little advice: use `get_user` instead of `fetch_user`, since `get_user` takes user from cache, and `fetch_use` makes an request, which can trigger ratelimit, e.g. on spam